# Setting new Screen in constructor does not display properly

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I made a placeholder Screen, since it was empty I just had it call the next screen in it's constructor. The next screen was running it's constructor but not showing the label I placed. When I skipped the placeholder Screen and went straight to the new Screen it was drawing it properly. Why?

**Place holder menu**

```
public PlaceHolderMenu()
{
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 720, 1280);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    skin = Assets.menuSkin;
    stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(TechnoFlux.WIDTH, TechnoFlux.HEIGHT, camera), batch);
    //No need for this screen yet so just call the next one...
    ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameScreen());
}
```

**The new Screen**

```
public GameScreen() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 720, 1280);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    skin = Assets.menuSkin;
    stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(TechnoFlux.WIDTH, TechnoFlux.HEIGHT, camera), batch);

    Label test = new Label("GAMESCREEN", skin, "largetext");

    bottomUI = new Table();
    bottomUI.row();
    bottomUI.add(test);
    bottomUI.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(bottomUI);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.2f, .2f, .3f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

All the above code was running but with the placeholder in between but it was not showing the label. I am pretty sure that when I add a button to the placeholder Screen that directs to the new Screen it will show again. I guess it has to do something with the assets loading or Screen class itself. I'm looking for some insights into this behavior.

Comment: Why don't you call ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameScreen()); in the render() method of PlaceHolderMenu? It would spare you from strange behaviour as you let the Screen class follow his regular lifecycle.

Comment: What happens if you put ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameScreen()); in the render method of placeholder instead of the constructor?